# Image is not downloading by C# , WebRequest.Create(url.AbsoluteUri) as HttpWebRequest;

Tags: c#, image, httpwebrequest

Previously all Images were downloadable from different website by using

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create(url.AbsoluteUri) as HttpWebRequest;
```

But now,I came across a website

http://www.euroman.dk/gadgets-og-design/det-onsker-vi-os/skyd-360-video-med-din-iphone/

and this Image URL is not downloadable

[http://www.euroman.dk/imagecropper.ashx?f=%2fUpload%2feuroman-dk%2fgadgets-og-design%2f2013%2520maj%2fthedot_01.jpg&w=643&h=405&m=1](http://www.euroman.dk/imagecropper.ashx?f=/Upload/euroman-dk/gadgets-og-design/2013%2520maj/thedot_01.jpg&w=643&h=405&m=1)

Can anybody suggest me please what is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your site expects an `User-Agent` header.

```
string url = "http://www.euroman.dk/imagecropper.ashx?f=%2fUpload%2feuroman-dk%2fgadgets-og-design%2f2013%2520maj%2fthedot_01.jpg&w=643&h=405&m=1";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12";
    byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pehaps set the timout with bigger value

```
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;
```